# Passing Argument to Python's Function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have this function:

`def fun(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3, arg4=4)`

Now if I want to call fun with arg1=8 then I will do this:

`fun(8)`

and if I want to call it with `arg1 = 8` and `arg2 = 9` then I think this will do (correct me if I am wrong):

`fun(8,9)  # LINE2`

How to call `fun` if I want to call it with the fourth `argument = 10`, without passing other argument values (let another argument have default valued)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fun(arg4=10)
```

You just have to reference the specific argument(s) by name.

Answer (score 1):

just provide the arguments you want and the others will get their default values:

`fun(arg4=10)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def fun(arg1=1,arg2=2,arg3=3,arg4=4):
        print arg4

>>> fun(arg4='I called you!')
I called you!
```

Just call the specific argument you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
def fun(arg1=1,arg2=2,arg3=3,arg4=4):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)
    print(arg4)
```

and you call

```
fun(arg4=10)
```

you will get

```
1
2
3
10
```

and it should be what you want to get